# Add Width to a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgimage

I have an image 96x96 and I would like to add extra width to it so that the new image is 120 x 96 with the image centered.

[image]

Above is an example of what I have. Below is what I want (Added width with the original image centered in it).

[image]

I've tried the following, but I get a weirdly cropped image:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithAddedWhitespaceFromImage:(UIImage *)image {

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(96, 96);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(12, 0, size.width + 24, size.height)];

    UIImage *newImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You need to create an image context of target size and then draw your image at original size. Comments in the code with `**` highlight my changes.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithAddedWhitespaceFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // ** Create context at target size of 120x96
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(120, 96);
    // ** Use this API for properly scaled image (instead of UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    // ** Now draw the image offset by 12px
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(12, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];    
    UIImage *newImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: You should also use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to get a properly scaled image.

Comment: You should also explain what was wrong and what you changed.